# Is there a way I can move a file to another drive and have a link to that file from its original place?

Tags: windows

Imagine a 126GB file `important.vbc` was in `C:/user/folder/important.vbc`

It is being used by some program but I'm running out of space in my `C:` drive.

So I decide to move it to `D:/user/important.vbc`

Is there a software/code I can put in `C:/user/folder/` to redirect any program finding important.vbc to `D:/user/` aka its new location?

I plan to do this on many files.

Comment: It's called a Symlink or Junction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. One way of doing it would be using Symbolic Links a.k.a Symlinks.

You can use the the `mklink` command from CMD to do that. (Run as administrator)

```
mklink /J C:/user/folder/important.vbc D:/user/important.vbc
```

> Symbolic links are basically advanced shortcuts. Create a symbolic link to an individual file or folder, and that link will appear to be the same as the file or folder to Windows—even though it’s just a link pointing at the file or folder.
>
> For example, let’s say you have a program that needs its files at
>   C:\Program. You’d really like to store this directory at D:\Stuff, but
>   the program requires that its files be at C:\Program. You could move
>   the original directory from C:\Program to D:\Stuff, and then create a
>   symbolic link at C:\Program pointing to D:\Stuff. When you relaunch
>   the program, it will try to access its directory at C:\Program.
>   Windows will automatically redirect it to D:\Stuff, and everything
>   will just work as if it were in C:\Program.
>
> This trick can be used for all sorts of things, including syncing any
>   folder with programs like Dropbox, Google Drive, and OneDrive.

For further reading: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: I don't think `mklink` is available in powershell.

Comment: @DavidDai Thanks for the correction! I've updated the answer.